# AWSSDK.SecurityToken could not be found or loaded on Linux with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, aws-sdk

I'm a bit stuck with a C# app that I'm working on, using .NET Core on Linux. I'm using AWSSDK.S3 to access files in a S3 bucket. There is a dependency on AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.SecurityToken.

At first it was complaining that AWSSDK.S3 and AWSSDK.Core were not found, I added the DLL, now it complains about AWSSDK.SecurityToken. I added the DLL also, into my exe folder, making sure it is in the PATH as well, but it is still not found.

Any idea on what I am missing? Is there a way to have logs about where it is searching for the DLL? Or about the version that it is trying to load?

Thanks,

Comment: I would use `dotnet publish` instead of doing manual steps

Comment: Make them all dependencies of your application in the `.csproj` file(s), then compile it, they should then ship with it when you publish it.

Comment: That is what I was doing, well, publishing in my build folder, then I need to zip this to install it on a server.
I tried anyway to publish on the server directly, but it just basically copy the 3 AWSSDK DLLs , and it is still not working.

Comment: ah... thanks guys, after digging a bit, it looks that the dependencies to AWSSDK that are in another libs were not propagated to my main project. the deps.json file wasn't referencing them. It looks better now, not working, but at list it finds the AWSSDK.SecurityToken